# Error "references strong named assembly. This is not allowed!"

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2012

I'm working with VS2012 (can't upgrade to newer version) and I have a solution that includes many projects.
Main project should produce a Class Library, this project depends on other projects that include external dlls

When I build each single project I get no errors, when I try to build the main one I get many of these errors:

```
Error   48  Interface component '<External library name>, Version=x.x.x.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' references strong named assembly '<External library name>, Version=x.x.x.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=############'. This is not allowed!     \EXEC  <Main Project Name>
Error   7   Interface component '<My project 1 name>, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' references strong named assembly '<External library name>, Version=x.x.x.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=############'. This is not allowed!    \EXEC   <Main Project Name>
Error   8   Interface component '<My project 2 name>, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' references strong named assembly '<External library name>, Version=x.x.x.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=############'. This is not allowed!    \EXEC   <Main Project Name>
```

I tried to add this code to App.config file but it doesn't work

```
  <runtime>
    <bypassTrustedAppStrongNames enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe this is some custom scripting somewhere in your build chain? _"This is not allowed!"_ doesn't sound like the sort of error message Microsoft would ship in a user-facing tool.

Comment: @MartinCostello thanks for your answer. The problem is that I have no idea about where I have to check

Comment: Try searching all your build scripts/batch files etc for the text `This is not allowed! `

Comment: @MatthewWatson I already tried but it didn't work. Thanks anyway

Comment: You could increase the log level of the build process by setting Tools - Options - "Projects and Solutions" - "Build and Run" and setting the verbosity of the build log to Diagnostic. Then you should see, who was being called to produce the message.

Comment: Thank @Oliver, I found who causes the error and it is an external software that tries to use the dll after the build process. If I don't call it, the build completes succesfully